# In the Writings of the Ancient Greeks---"God is Everywhere Implied"

Tags: reference-request, philosophy, greek, existence-of-god, plato

Elements of monotheism seem to have existed in the philosophies of at least several of the celebrated ancient Greek philosophers; *e.g.,* Parmenides, Socrates, Plato, and Aristotle.

A while back, I recall have read (but I can't recall exactly where) that in the writings of the ancients, "God is everywhere implied."

Can someone point me to who may have written or uttered this; and also, and if such writings extended beyond ancient Greek philosophy?

*Remarks:* I thought perhaps the statement might have come from St. Thomas Aquinas because he was very much influenced by Aristotle---but so far, have found nothing. Also, I thought perhaps I would find the desired remark in St. Basil's "Address to young men on the right use of Greek literature," but it seemed to me to disclose nothing of the sort.

Thank you.